# use vertcat to get 1 dimensional data

Tags: matlab, svd

suppose that we have  following matrices

```
>> X=create_matrix1(B,20);
>> [U E V]=svd(X);
```

in other word we have matrix and we are going to do svd  of this matrix,then it is clear that following thing

```
z=vertcat(U(:,1),U(:,2),U(:,3));
```

dimension of this  vector is

```
[m,n]=size(z)

m =

   825


n =

     1
```

while  following thing

```
z1=vertcat(U(:,1:3));
[m,n]=size(z1)

m =

   275


n =

     3
```

so how can i fix this?thanks in advance
EDITED:  i want to concatenate for instance  first d  left and right  matrix column using vertcat function

Comment: `vertcat` contanenates matrices, not columns of a matrix. I think what you need is `U(:)`.

Comment: no no,vertcat concatenates columns of matrices  also

Comment: U(:,1) is  column of  U matrix

Comment: No, it doesn't concatenate columns of matrix, unless you input those columns as _separate matrices_. Compare `vertcat([1 1; 1 1])` and `vertcat([1; 1],[1; 1])`

Comment: so how can i   columns as  separate matrix with loop?like  in the first example,like there  :z=vertcat(U(:,1),U(:,2),U(:,3));

Comment: As I said, `z=vertcat(U(:,1),U(:,2),U(:,3));` is the same as `z=U(:);`

Comment: yes but there can be  other columns,maybe his matrix has 8 column

Comment: `U(:)` works no matter how many columns `U` has... Sorry, your question is very unclear

Comment: no no my friend,i want to concatenate vertically three column of my matrix

Comment: i dont want to concatenate all columns,but  some  part of them,let say first 5 column,i can do as vertcat(U(:,1),U(:,2),U(:,3),U(:,4),U(:,5)),but how can i do using loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop if you use `reshape`:

```
cols = [1:3];
z1 = reshape(U(:,cols), numel(U(:,cols)), 1);
```

You can also use this for non-consecutive columns, for example:

```
cols = [1 2 4 7];
```

Example:

```
A = [1 2 3;
     4 5 6;
     7 8 9]

cols = [1:2];
B = reshape(A(:,cols), numel(A(:,cols)), 1)
```

The output is:

```
A =

   1   2   3
   4   5   6
   7   8   9

B =

   1
   4
   7
   2
   5
   8
```

Comment: what if i need  concatenate also columns of V matrix

Comment: z1 = concatenated U columns; z2 = concatenated V columns; z3 = [z1; z2]; You might want to put all of your requirements in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
startRange = 1;
StopRange = 5;
for ii = startRange:stopRange
    col=U(:,ii)
    newmat = [newmat; col]
end
```

Comment: so finally vertcat or?

Comment: No, line 5 IS vertcat. : )